# canvas overlay export

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have 2 canvas, canvas1 and canvas2. Both work well, but I want to mix them to export as image. Overlay css based do not work as it prints 2 images. Any point to start? thank you.

```
<canvas id="canvas1" style="position:relative; float:left;border:1px solid #000 "     width="547" height="154">
</canvas>

<canvas id="canvas2" style="z-index: 1; position:absolute; float:left;" width="547" height="500">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a few ways to go about this, and what do you mean by mix?

If you simply want to overlay canvas2 over canvas1, but don't want to alter either original canvas, you can send their data to another canvas, and then get that data.

method to follow:

```
draw canvas1 to canvas3
draw canvas2 to canvas3
get  canvas3 image
```

working javascript:

```
// Make all the canvas and context variables */
var c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
var c2 = document.getElementById('c2');
var c3 = document.getElementById('c3');
var c4 = document.getElementById('c4');

var ctx1 = c1.getContext('2d');
var ctx2 = c2.getContext('2d');
var ctx3 = c3.getContext('2d');
var ctx4 = c4.getContext('2d');
/* */

// Draw square on canvas 1
ctx1.fillRect(0,0,50,50);

// Draw offset square on canvas 2
ctx2.fillRect(25,25,50,50);

// Make third image and onload function
var img3 = new Image();
img3.onload = function(){
  // Draw this image to canvas 4 so that we know it worked
  ctx4.drawImage(this,0,0);
}

// So we know when both have loaded
var imagesLoaded = 0;
function draw(){
  // increment number loaded
  imagesLoaded++;

  // draw this image to canvas 3
  ctx3.drawImage(this,0,0);

  // if the have both loaded, then...
  if (imagesLoaded == 2){

    // set third image's src to the canvas 3 image
    img3.src = c3.toDataURL();
  }

}

// First image
var img1 = new Image();
// So it will draw on canvas 3
img1.onload = draw;
// Set the src to canvas 1's image
img1.src = c1.toDataURL();


// Second image
var img2 = new Image();
// So it will draw on canvas 3
img2.onload = draw;
// Set the src to canvas 2's image
img2.src = c2.toDataURL();
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/crzyman/6zE8M/).

However, if that wasn't what you were looking for, I am sorry.